# Show $P(Y<y) =P(X \le \sqrt{y})$

Tags: probability

Hello I am stuck on part b). Anyone have any suggestions? Not sure where to start. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hint: think of the probability as a measure on the sample space of events. For every event, usually denoted as $\omega$, you measure $X(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)$, the random variables. Now the events were $Y \le y$ are exactly the same events where $X \le \sqrt{y}$. Since the probability depends only on which events you are considering and not on how you "parametrize" them, the probabilities are the same.

Comment: There is not here much to "prove", but only to "understand" the result, in my opinion

Comment: I don't believe that part (c) is asking for a proof of a true statement. The CDF of $Y$ _does not_ increase in a straight line from $0$ to $4$.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the reply, but how would I go about showing algebraically the two events are the same? Is it a case that since R.V. Y= X^2, so y=x^2? And then sub into the expression? Don’t quite know how to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For point (b) this is how I would try to formalize, following the comments above.

Let $y>0$.

$I=\{ \omega \in \Omega | Y(\omega) \le y\}=\{ \omega \in \Omega | X^2(\omega) \le y\}=\{ \omega \in \Omega | |X(\omega)| \le \sqrt{y}\}=\{ \omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) \le \sqrt{y}\}$

because $X$ is positive. Told another way, the events $Y \le y$ and  $X \le \sqrt{y}$ are the same therefore they have equal probability.

Comment: There is a small detail missing : the event in the question is  $Y < y$ and not $Y \leq y.$

Comment: True. But I think that the events differ by a set of measure zero, given that we have a finite density, so that we can easily change $<$ with $\le$ and viceversa in all expressions.